# Framebuffer completeness - glTexImage2D and glRenderBufferStorageMultiSample

Tags: opengl

I test a different framebuffer completeness scenarios. Please see the following example:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);

glGenTextures(1, &texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId, 0);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboId);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, w, h);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

GLenum drawBuffers[]{ GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    return false;
}
```

I have expected to get status different than `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE` because a depth attachment has different samples count than a color attachment. Could you please explain why that framebuffer is complete.

Comment: You should check for errors using [`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml).  Does the call to `glFramebufferRenderbuffer` succeed?

Comment: glGetErrors called just before just before glCheckFramebufferStatus doesn't return any errors. glDebugMessageCallback returns the following info: *Framebuffer detailed info: The driver allocated multisample storage for renderbuffer 1.*

Comment: Which OpenGL driver(s) you have checked so far?

Comment: On implementations exposing the [AMD_framebuffer_multisample_advanced](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/AMD/AMD_framebuffer_multisample_advanced.txt) extension, this is perfectly allowed. GL extensions often result in relaxing some of the stricter requirements in the core spec without your code having to call any specific extension function.